# JavaScript Global variable value changes on Function value

Tags: javascript

Why am i getting two different results from the below code. The only change i am doing is passing the value to a function, in first code i am getting the value of global variable "count" as 10 and in the second code the global variables("count") value changes to 30.

```js
            function addTen(count) {
                count = count + 20;
                return count;
            }
            
            var count = 10
            var result = addTen(count);
            console.log(count);    //10
            console.log(result);   //30
```

```js
            function addTen(num) {
                count = num + 20;
                return count;
            }
            
            var count = 10
            var result = addTen(count);
            console.log(count);    //30
            console.log(result);   //30
```

Comment: The first one doesn't affect the global `count` because it's shadowed by the argument with the same name.

Comment: Because in the first example you are "overwriting" the global variable count with the parameter *count* and in the second one no.

Answer (score 0):

In your second function, the statement

```
count = num + 20;
```

assigns to the global variable (it's the only `count` in scope). To make it a local variable for the function scope only, and not affect the global, use

```
var count = num + 20;
```

In your first function, the parameter `count` implicitly declares such a local variable, shadowing the global variable of the same name.